# Passing database connection to multiple Tonic gRPC services

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tokio, rust-tonic

I am trying to share my SeaORM connection with multiple gRPC services.

```
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let config = config::load();
    let conn = connection::get(&config.database).await;

    let addr = format!("{}:{}", config.server.host, config.server.port).parse()?;

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(MyGreeter { connection: conn }))
        .add_service(HealthServer::new(HealthCheck { connection: conn }))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

However after the second service (HealthCheck) I am getting "value used here after move".
How do I solve this?

---

This is how I am passing the connection to each service:

```
use sea_orm::DatabaseConnection;
use tonic::{Request, Response, Status};

pub mod hello_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld"); // The string specified here must match the proto package name
}
pub use hello_world::greeter_server::{Greeter, GreeterServer};
use hello_world::{HelloReply, HelloRequest};

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyGreeter {
    pub connection: DatabaseConnection,
}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Greeter for MyGreeter {
    async fn unary(
        &self,
        request: Request<HelloRequest>, // Accept request of type HelloRequest
    ) -> Result<Response<HelloReply>, Status> {
        // Return an instance of type HelloReply
        println!("Got a request: {:?}", request);

        let reply = hello_world::HelloReply {
            message: format!("Hello {}!", request.into_inner().name).into(), // We must use .into_inner() as the fields of gRPC requests and responses are private
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply)) // Send back our formatted greeting
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in this way. I think this is not a very optimal use, it needs to be investigated how it affects the number of connections and thread safety.

```
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let config = config::load();
    let conn = connection::get(&config.database).await;

    let addr = format!("{}:{}", config.server.host, config.server.port).parse()?;

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(MyGreeter { connection: conn.clone() }))
        .add_service(HealthServer::new(HealthCheck { connection: conn.clone() }))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```